# Tag synonymy arayot to replace by [tag:isure-bia]

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

For all halachic topic concerning prohibited sexual intercoure, I feel interesting to re-group the topic to **Issure Bia**, following the Rambam category, instead of the olds Arayot, giluy-arayot erva.

Despite that Isure Bia contains in Rambam Hilchot Nidda, I feel that this can be also a discussion to include nidda in Isure Bia.

Is someone interested to re-group isure Bia? [isure-bia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isure-bia)

[arayot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arayot); [gilui-arayos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gilui-arayos); [erva](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erva); [adultery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adultery)

Comment: Could you please [edit] this proposal to be a great deal more clear? What are the existing tags? (Use `[tag:tag-name]` format to make clear links.) What collection should there be instead? (Again, use that format, or just enclose proposed tag names with backticks: ``.) What should the conceptual boundaries between them be? Why is your proposed division superior to the existing one?

Comment: I believe that now it is a little mor clear